# Create a bounding box for a GeoTIFF using GDAL on the commandline

Tags: gdal, bash

How can I create a bounding box for a GeoTIFF using GDAL on the commandline?

I often have a folder of TIFFs that I want to generate GeoJSONs for.

I'd rather not make a Python script, since it's a lot easier to keep GDAL working directly as command line utilities than it is to keep it working in Python for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out gdaltindex is designed for this exact purpose. It makes an OGR file from a set of TIFFs (or other rasters).

Here's the command I used:

```
gdaltindex -f GeoJSON allmytifs.geojson *.tif
```

Comment: Depending on what you want to achieve, gdal_footprint may be even better https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_footprint.html. It will be published in the next GDAL release v. 3.8. But it takes just one filename as input, not `*.tif`.